# Collecting logs from Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, clickonce, isolatedstorage

We are designing a system with a WPF client.

We plan for the WPF client to be deployed using click once and log to a file on isolated storage.

The question is how can we read these log files? We can write code to view the log in the application. But, is it possible to read the logs on all client machines from a central location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would probably be better is to send the logs from the client to the server. This eliminates the problem of finding the location of each client and accessing its isolated storage.